# Query in repository not translated correctly

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, java-11

I am quite a beginner with Spring Data, and I have to code my first difficult query :)

I am making a reservation engine for an event. My data model is composed by:

- a `RoomType` entity defining a possible configuration for a room (e.g. double, triple, quadruple)
- a `Room` entity representing the actual Room
- a `RoomArrangement` entity defining all the possible `RoomTypes` for a `Room` (e.g. the room 7 can be configured as Triple or Double room)
- a `RoomAssignment` entity representing the actual configuration chosen for a room after having been reserved

FKs are configured this way
`RoomType <--* RoomArrangement *--> Room <-- RoomAssignment`
(see code below for Entity definition)

I need to find the `Room` without an `Assignment` that has the highest Priority (= nearest to 1) for a given `RoomType`.

I have configured Spring as below.

RoomType.java

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "room_type_id")
private List<RoomArrangement> roomArrangements;
```

RoomArrangement.java

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = RoomType.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "room_type_id", nullable = false)
private RoomType roomType;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Room.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "room_id", nullable = false)
private Room room;

@Column(name = "priority")
private Integer priority;
```

Room.java

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "room_id")
private List<RoomArrangement> roomArrangements;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "room", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private RoomAssignment assignment;
```

RoomArrangementRepository.java

```
RoomArrangement findFirstByRoomTypeAndRoom_AssignmentIsNullOrderByPriorityAsc(RoomType rt);
```

The query above is translated to

```
select 
roomarrang0_.id as id1_3_, 
    roomarrang0_.priority as priority2_3_, 
    roomarrang0_.room_id as room_id3_3_, 
    roomarrang0_.room_type_id as room_typ4_3_ 
from 
room_arrangements roomarrang0_ 
    left outer join 
    rooms room1_ on roomarrang0_.room_id=room1_.id 
where 
    roomarrang0_.room_type_id=9     
    and 
    (room1_.id is null)
order by 
    roomarrang0_.priority asc 
limit 1;
```

The issues are two:

1. I do not know where the where clause
   (room1_.id is null)
   comes from
2. I do not know where the "AndRoom_AssignmentIsNull" clause has gone

Should I "invert" the OneToOne relationship and put the FK on the Room class?

Thanks for your help!
Lorenzo

---

I've tried to apply some of the suggestions, and "turned" the query on the RoomRepository.

The query came like this:

```
Room findFirstByRoomArrangements_RoomTypeAndAssignmentIsNullOrderByRoomArrangements_PriorityAsc(RoomType rt);
```

We come to the same problem:
    select 
        room0_.id as id1_6_, 
        room0_.room_name as room_nam2_6_ 
    from 
        rooms room0_ 
        left outer join 
        room_arrangements roomarrang1_ on room0_.id=roomarrang1_.room_id 
    where 
        roomarrang1_.room_type_id=? 
        and 
        (room0_.id is null) 
    order by 
        roomarrang1_.priority asc 
    limit ?;

I think the problem lies in the fact that the one-to-one relationship between Room and RoomAssignment is represented on the database with a FK on the room_assignments table to the rooms table.

I will try to put the FK on the rooms table instead of on the room_assignments table and see if something changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find a room without an without an Assignment, shouldn't you be looking that in the Room repository?

Answer (score 1):

You said that you have to find a `Room` but you are returning a `RoomArrangement` in a `RoomAssignmentRepository`. This is quite confusing.

Let's assume you are in right place, that means `RoomRepository` and as you said:

> I need to find the Room without an Assignment that has the highest Priority (= nearest to 1) for a given RoomType.

try to use the following method name

`Room findByRoomArrangementRoomTypeAndRoomAssignmentIsNullOrderByPriorityAsc(RoomType rt)`

Comment: Question error: the query is in the RoomArrangement repository
I will try this strategy. Just, I have to order by RoomArrangement_Priority probably :)

Comment: question is now correct. Unfortunately I picked two similar names and got confused myself :)

Answer (score 0):

Made it!
In the end, the problem lied in the fact that the one-to-one relationship between Room and RoomAssignment was mapped by an FK from RoomAssignment to Room. Apparently, Spring Data didn't manage this configuration properly: the Assignment is null was translated to room_assignment.room_id = null and, since room_id was an FK to room.id, to room.id = null.

Inverting the FK mapping, the query is translated to

```
select 
    room0_.id as id1_6_, 
    room0_.assignment_id as assignme3_6_, 
    room0_.room_name as room_nam2_6_ 
from 
    rooms room0_ 
    left outer join room_arrangements roomarrang1_ on room0_.id=roomarrang1_.room_id 
where 
    roomarrang1_.room_type_id=? 
    and (room0_.assignment_id is null) 
order by 
    roomarrang1_.priority asc 
limit ?
```

which correctly returns what I needed.